# Connecting to motor controller input ground drops system voltage

Tags: grounding

I am currently working on installing photoelectric sensors into motor controller inputs. The inputs to the motor controller are 24V open ended inputs. The supply source is a 48/24 V buck chopper. When I connect the signal of the sensor into the input with without running a ground wire connecting the cold wire of sensor (connected to system 0V) to the micro controller the inputs see 24V when sensor is on and the motors perform exactly as expected when they reach their physical limits (stop moving). When I connect the ground wire the whole 24 volt system (of 3 other motors on same 24V line as well as 24V lighting system all fed from buck chopper) drops to 18V.

There is a serious hole in my understanding of grounding, as I would have figured ground reference would be necessary for the input to know what 24V is. Furthermore why is the system voltage dropping? The entire system is quite complicated and the 0V of different systems are connected interchangeably as opposed to each system has own return route to 0V. Is the 24V likely not grounded properly and by properly connecting the 0V to the motor controller GND the system 0V changes its reference to the 24 or am I likely introducing a ground fault somehow? Any assistance or links to reference material / good textbooks would be appreciated. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Your motor controller cannot possibly work if it only has one connection to Din and nothing powering it. Show the complete diagram, and include whether the DC converter is isolating or not, otherwise there's an obvious ground path through it.

Comment: The motor controller is is directly mounted to the motor. The power supply to the motor (48V positive and negative) would be the ground reference in this case. A complete diagram and peek at DC converter datasheet would not be possible for 24 hours. Are you implying that an isolating DC converter would have a different ground reference than the motor's 48V ground and by unwittingly joining both grounds I have changed the frame of reference for the 24V line?